# Use rollup.js with jQuery adaptor in same file

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I have the main function to export and the jQuery adaptor in the same file. And I would like to keep them this way.

Is there a way with rollup.js to create the bundle file compatible with AMD, CommonJS and Browsers?

Right now I have this test file:

```
//src/foo.js
export default function(){
    function initialise() {
        var TEST = {};
        TEST.version = '1.0.0';
        TEST.hello = function(){
            console.log("hello man!!");
        };

        return TEST;
    }

    //jQuery adapter
    (function($){
        $.fn.demo = function(options) {
            $.fn.demo.test = 'test';
        };
    })(jQuery);

    return initialise;
};
```

And I tried using this rollup config:

```
// rollup.config.js
export default {
  input: 'src/main.js',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/bundle.js',
    format: 'umd',
    globals: {
        $: '$'
    }
  }
};
```

However I can't seem to have access to `$.fn.demo`:

```
// src/main.js
import jQuery from 'jQuery';
import pepe from './foo.js';


console.log(jQuery);    //<--- undefined
console.log($);         //<--- undefined

console.log("-- JS--");
console.log(pepe);      //<---- working fine
console.log("-- $.fn.demo --");
console.log($.fn.demo); //<--- undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your `main.js` file `pepe` is a function (one which you exported from `foo`) and you didn't call it hence `$.fn.demo` is `undefined`. You must call `pepe();` in order for you adapter to be executed.

See also [how to tell Rollup that jquery is external and the jquery module ID equates to the global $ variable](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#output-globals-g-globals).